# A-frame Local Video could not display

Tags: aframe

I want to display a local video with A-frame, and at the same computer.But,on the browser, nothing display, the screen is black(seems that no render).
I just do a little change on the 360-video source code, and I am newer of Web developer. So please help me, and tell me where is my wrong.
My source code is those:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>360 Video</title>
      <meta name="description" content="360 Video — A-Frame">
      <script src="../../../dist/aframe-master.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <!-- tt.mp4 is my video file and with index.html at the same folder -->
      <video id="video" src="tt.mp4" autoplay loop crossorigin></video>
    </a-assets>

  <a-videosphere src="#video" rotation="0 180 0"></a-videosphere>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to do this locally because (despite the `crossorigin` attribute) your browser probably doesn't allow the reference. I would recommend initiating a local php server with a `index.php` file that contains `<?php include_once("[your-aframe-file].html"); ?>`. This way your php server is recognized as a single origin. If you're on a running MacOS or Linux I know the command line command is just `php -S localhost:8000` from the project directory.